# Running a sqlite3 directly from ADB shell (for monkeyrunner)

Tags: android, sqlite, monkeyrunner

I'd like to run a sqlite3 query from a monkeyrunner script of mine.

Ideally I'd like to be able to write code like this:

```
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
sql_query = "select * from myTable;"
device.shell("sqlite3 /path/to/db/ --sql " + sql_query)
```

Is there an easy way to get sqlite3 execute some SQL passed in as an arg (as apposed to opening an interpreter)?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for sqlite3 command line is `sqlite3 [OPTIONS] FILENAME [SQL]`. So you can do something along the lines of

```
sqlite3 /path/to/db 'select * from foo;'
```